# Как использовать paginator в HTML tempalte?

Tags: python, django

Я хочу получить номер следующей страницы. Для этого есть `page.next_page_number()`. Во `view` всё работает, а в `template` нет. Хотя в  [документациии всё сделано также](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/).
У меня  в HTML  коде ничего не отображается на месте `{{ page.next_page_number }}`.

Comment: приведите пример вашего нерабочего кода

Answer (score 1):

Если используете generic views, то, скорее всего, имя объекта в шаблоне не `page`, а `page_obj`